# C header files are missing after upgrading OSX to Majove 10.14.4

Tags: c, macos, header-files, macos-mojave

Header files like `stdio.h` and `string.h` should be located in `/usr/include` but they have been removed after upgrading macOS to the current latest version. (10.14.4)

The compile progress may succeed (built-in clang may find these header files elsewhere) but code completion supported by IDEs cannot work without these header files located in the right place.

The following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

May be considered error (header file not found).

Fortunately, I found `stdio.h` by using `locate` command and it was located in   `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/`, but this directory is not automatically included in CLion.

I'm not sure creating a symbolic link or just copy all these files to `/usr/include` can work without bad side effects.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for my self-answer.

But I think this could be useful to others who accidentally upgrade their macOS to 10.14.4.

```sh
open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

Run this command and you can have all header files installed in the right place.